# Angular 9 - @angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDef'

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic4, node-modules

I keep getting this error when trying to run ionic serve command in terminal.

I have looked this up and seen I need to delete the npm_modules file and reinstall

What is the command for this? or how do i do it?

Comment: Delete `node_modules` and run `npm install`.

Comment: How do i do this? is there a specific command?

Comment: That's literally the command. Delete the `node_modules` folder, then run `npm install` in your terminal.

Comment: `npm_modules` is a **folder**, not a file. It's a sibling folder of src folder in a cli project.